# Tika 0.10 is able to extract metadata, but it is not able to insert it into its XHTML output

Tags: java, apache-tika

```
public class TikaParserImpl implements TikaParser
{
    private AutoDetectParser parser;

    public TikaParserImpl()
    {
        parser = new AutoDetectParser();
    }

    @Override
    public String parse(InputStream in) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException
    {
        TransformerHandler handler;
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        try
        {
            handler = getTransformerHandler(writer);
        }
        catch (TransformerConfigurationException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
        ParseContext context = new ParseContext();
        parser.parse(in, handler, metadata, context);

        String[] metanames = metadata.names();
        for (int i = 0; i < metanames.length; i++) {
            String[] metavalues = metadata.getValues(metanames[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < metavalues.length; j++) {
                LOG.warn(metanames[i] + ": " + metavalues[j]);
            }
        }

        String output = writer.toString();
        return output;
    }

    /**
     * Get a TransformerHandler.
     * 
     * The handler is used to convert SAX events to a XHTML document.
     * 
     * Since this object might not be multi-threaded, it is re-created at each
     * parsing.
     * 
     * @param writer
     * @return TransformerHandler
     * @throws TransformerConfigurationException
     */
    private TransformerHandler getTransformerHandler(StringWriter writer) throws TransformerConfigurationException
    {
        // Even the factory might not be multi-threaded, so we don't take chance
        SAXTransformerFactory factory = (SAXTransformerFactory) SAXTransformerFactory.newInstance();
        TransformerHandler handler = factory.newTransformerHandler();
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
        handler.getTransformer().setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        handler.setResult(new StreamResult(writer));
        return handler;
    }
}
```

I am new to tika, and this code I'm working on wasn't written by me so I'm new to it as well. The expectation here is that XHTML is generated from whatever this thing parses. For some documents (eg: Office's xls format), everything is fine. For others (eg: Office's xlsx format), I do not get the metadata in the XHTML but it's still there in the instance of Metadata (as you can see I log the contents of the metadata class).

Unfortunately, I can not use a newer version of Tika as this will break the version of Nutch that I'm stuck with as well.

Comment: Are there any exceptions or does it just 'not work'?

Comment: no exceptions. However, modern versions of Tika do work. It's just unfortunate that I'm not in a position to just upgrade right now.